# Gmail: Seeing all correspondence with "sender"?

Tags: gmail

Is there a new, easy way to generate this search?
"from:sender@example.com OR to:sender@example.com"

The old, easy way (hover, click) has been removed.
An easy way should not involve typing in the search box.
Also, I really do not want to create a unique filter and label for every such sender.